# How to convert a pre-instanced callback into Observable

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm fairly new to RxJava and I have a basic understanding as to how to wrap a callback into an Observable but what I'm having difficulty with is doing so when the callback/listener is pre-instanced. Every example that I have found only shows instancing the callback directly into the Observable being created.

Some example code of what I'm talking about. I'm working with an Api that's works like this:

```java
public class Api {
    private ApiCallback callback;

    void initialize(ApiCallback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    void doAction1(){
        this.callback.onAction1Complete();
    }
}

interface ApiCallback {
    void onInitialized();

    void onAction1Complete();
}
```

With the real api I am working with I have no control over how it works so I must work with it in this state. In terms of trying to work with this Api using observables here is the struggle I am having. I have a member variable that holds the Api object:

```java
private Api mApi = new Api();
```

Now in order to initialize this I have one of two options it seems.

Option 1:

```java
    Completable startApi() {
        return Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(final CompletableEmitter emitter) throws Exception {
                mApi.initialize(new ApiCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitialized() {
                        emitter.onComplete();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAction1Complete() {

                    }

                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Option 2:

```java
    private ApiCallback premadeCallback = new ApiCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onInitialized() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAction1Complete() {
        }
    };

    Completable startApi() {
        return Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(final CompletableEmitter emitter) throws Exception {
                mApi.initialize(premadeCallback);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now the issue I have is that Option 2 makes more sense to me when I need to know when the other methods in the callback are called from Api calls. With my understanding of RxJava however I don't understand how I can reach these method calls with an Api that works like this.

For example:

```java
    Completable doAction1() {
        return Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(final CompletableEmitter emitter) throws Exception {
                // Api is already initialized with callback
                // How do I reach the callback from here?
            }
        });
    }
```

The only what that I can currently think of as to how to achieve this would be to create a member variable as an emitter (or a dictionary of emitters) and then call its appropriate method in the api callback when needed. My concerns with this are A. I'm unsure if RxJava can work this way B. This sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: If you want the Api class to trigger the onSuccess signal of you Completable, you can implement the ApiCallback using a `CompletableSubject`. This way you will not miss the signal emitted.

Comment: This looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.